# Icons are not displayed properly with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

The icon is not displayed, it's only displayed after closing for half a second:

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1600, 900)) 
pygame.display.set_caption(‘Elizabeth2’) 
icon = pygame.image.load('reindeer.png') 
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
```

Comment: Please include some description of what your code is meant to do, and what your problem is.

Answer (score 4):

See [`pygame.display.set_icon()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_icon):

> [...] Some systems do not allow the window icon to change after it has been shown. This function can be called before `pygame.display.set_mode()` to create the icon before the display mode is set.

Set the icon before `pygame.display.set_mode((1600, 900))`:

```py
icon = pygame.image.load('reindeer.png') 
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1600, 900))
pygame.display.set_caption(‘Elizabeth2’)
```

---

In addition, the size of the icon is limited:

> [...] You can pass any surface, but most systems want a smaller image around 32x32.

If the icon is not displayed, try a smaller icon.

---

Make sure that the resource (image) path and the working directory is correct.

The image file path has to be relative to the current working directory. The working directory is possibly different to the directory of the python file.

The name and path of the file can be get by [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes). The current working directory can be get by [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) and can be changed by [`os.chdir(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).

```py
import os

sourceFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(sourceFileDir)
```

An alternative solution is to find the absolute path.
If the image is relative to the folder of the python file (or even in the same folder), then you can get the directory of the file and join ([`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)) the image filename. e.g.:

```py
import pygame
import os

# get the directory of this file
sourceFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

iconPath = os.path.join(sourceFileDir, 'reindeer.png')
icon = pygame.image.load(iconPath) 
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
```